# Better ways for merging data from two sources using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have some C#/Linq code used to merge data from excel file into db, which needs better performance.

There are
1. A List read from excel file: `List<Score> newScoreList`
2. A DB table named `Scores`, primary keys `peopleId` and `testDate`

I need to merge data from the list to the table, and if there is any duplicate data, update it.

My current solution is:

1) Find the duplicate data with this LINQ expression:

```
var dupliData =  
    from newScore in newScoreList  
    from oldScore in db.Scores  
    where newScore.peopleId == oldScore.peopleId && newScore.testDate == oldScore.testDate  
    select oldScore;
```

2) Delete the duplicate data.

```
db.Scores.DeleteAllOnSubmit(dupliData);
```

3) Insert the new data from list.

```
db.Scores.InsertAllOnSubmit(newScoreList);
```

Could anybody give me a better solution?

Comment: Do you must delete and recreate them? Or can you just update the existing row, which should yield better performance.

Comment: Have you looked in SQL Profiler, are there an unusual number of queries of some kind?

Comment: How many records are we talking about and where is the performance probem? The select? The Delete? The insert? Because large amounts of Inserts with Linq are anyway going to give you performance - in that case you should look at SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, you are right, my codes waste too much time scanning the list again and again, it could be done in one time scanning.

Comment: @Albin I don't konw SQL Profiler before, but I will try it, thanks!

Comment: Hi, @Pleun, the records number is around 10,000 both in table and list . The linq expression I mentioned in my question costs a lot of time querying the duplicate data, so I want to get an idea which solves the problem and provides better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really hate stored procedures in general, but this is `probably` a perfect case for using one. My TSQL is rusty, but this should give an idea.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertOrUpdateScore
(
    @id as Int,
    @date as DateTime,
    @result as varchar(20)
)
AS

if not exists(SELECT id FROM Scores WHERE id = @id AND date = @date)
begin
   INSERT INTO Scores (id, date, result) values (@id, @date, @result)
end
else
begin
   UPDATE Scores
   SET result = @result
   WHERE id = @id AND date = @date
end
GO
```

Now in your LINQ server browser, select the Score entity, and change its INSERT and UPDATE behaviour to use the stored procedure you just created. Make sure the user accessing the database has EXECUTE permission to the SPROC.

This should perform quite a bit quicker than your version. You're trading an IN clause for N SELECTs on an index which may be quicker. However, the result set of the IN clause is not transported back to the client over the network, which could save quite a bit of time.

Profile exactly how long your method is taking before implementing this, so you can gauge if this is truly quicker.

I'm not sure if this is the only way to create a Score in your application, but you might want to consider the case where you're INSERTing a record that doesn't yet have an ID. You'll need to modify the SPROC to allow `@id` as `null`, and handle the INSERT appropriately.

Then it *should* just be:

```
db.Scores.InsertAllOnSubmit(newScoreList);
```

Comment: thanks for your good answer and detailed explanation. I'm not familiar with SPROC, by following your logic I rewrite the code, use hashtable to contain data and do query. The performance is much better now. But I believe your solution using SPROC must provide even better performance.

Comment: You don't keed to use an sproc. You can use inline-sql as well.

Comment: @usr, I'm not a fan of inline-sql within applications unless absolutely required. If it was a simple select; maybe. But this involves SQL logic, and is in all senses of the word a procedure/method. You can write the method in c# or in a sproc. The point is, whether you are inserting or updating, with the requirements specified, the same logic is required for both.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL 2008 you can use the Merge command
http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Using-SQL-Server-2008-s-MERGE-statement/0,339028455,339283059,00.htm

Comment: Thanks @Pleun, though I'm actually using sql 2000 but this command is interesting